# Difference between XPathEvaluate on XElement or XDocument?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement

Somewhere in a C# program, I need to get an attribute value from an xml structure. I can reach this xml structure directly as an XElement and have a simple xpath string to get the attribute. However, using XPathEvaluate, I get an empty array most of the time. (Yes, sometimes, the attribute is returned, but mostly it isn't... for the exact same XElement and xpath string...)
However, if I first convert the xml to string and reparse it as an XDocument, I do always get the attribute back. Can somebody explain this behavior ? (Am using .NET 3.5)

Code that mostly returns an empty IEnumerable:

```
string xpath = "/exampleRoot/exampleSection[@name='test']/@value";
XElement myXelement = RetrieveXElement();
((IEnumerable)myXElement.XPathEvaluate(xpath)).Cast<XAttribute>().FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Code that does always work (I get my attribute value):

```
string xpath = "/exampleRoot/exampleSection[@name='test']/@value";
string myXml = RetrieveXElement().ToString();
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(myXml);
((IEnumerable)xdoc.XPathEvaluate(xpath)).Cast<XAttribute>().FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

With the test xml:

```
<exampleRoot>
    <exampleSection name="test" value="2" />
    <exampleSection name="test2" value="2" />
</exampleRoot>
```

By suggestion related to a surrounding root, I did some 'dry tests' in a test program, using the same xml structure (txtbxXml and txtbxXpath representing the xml and xpath expression described above):

```
// 1. XDocument Trial:
((IEnumerable)XDocument.Parse(txtbxXml.Text).XPathEvaluate(txtbxXPath.Text)).Cast<XAttribute>().FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString();
// 2. XElement trial:
((IEnumerable)XElement.Parse(txtbxXml.Text).XPathEvaluate(txtbxXPath.Text)).Cast<XAttribute>().FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString();
// 3. XElement originating from other root:
((IEnumerable)(new XElement("otherRoot", XElement.Parse(txtbxXml.Text)).Element("exampleRoot")).XPathEvaluate(txtbxXPath.Text)).Cast<XAttribute>().FirstOrDefault().Value.ToString();
```

Result : case 1 and 3 produce the correct result, while case 2 throws a nullref exception.
If case 3 would fail and case 2 succeed, it would have made some sense to me, but now I don't get it...

Comment: what does `RetrieveXElement()` do.

Comment: RetrieveXElement() is some method in my code which returns a valid XElement. For the sake of simplicity lets say RetrieveXElment is 'XElement.Parse(theTestXml);'

Comment: Why use XPath with `System.Xml.Linq`?

Comment: Why not? My program builds the xml in memory, using LINQ (for obvious reasons). Is there a better way to get to a specific attribute instead of using xpath? I'd surely like to know.
But still interested in what causes the difference XElement/XDocument too...

Comment: Maybe in your first case, the element you consider to be root, isn't the root...you could try it like this: "//exampleRoot/exampleSection[@name='test']/@value". I post this as a comment, not as an answer, since it's just a guess.

Comment: I noticed you have another very interesting: ".NET GDI+ drawing performance". I gave it an upvote so it gets the attention it deserves. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that the XPath expression is starting with the children of the specified node. If you start with an `XDocument`, the root element is the child node. If you start with an `XElement` representing your `exampleRoot` node, then the children are the two `exampleSection` nodes.

If you change your XPath expression to `"/exampleSection[@name='test']/@value"`, it will work from the element. If you change it to `"//exampleSection[@name='test']/@value"`, it will work from both the `XElement` and the `XDocument`.

Comment: Really useful to know and not as expected. Thanks for sharing as you saved me quite a lot (more) wasted time trying to work out why my selectors were not working!